# populate bootstrap dropdown on the base.html using django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Im using django 1.9 and python 3.5 which i'm both really new too, and i'm having trouble populating a bootstrap dropdown which is located in the base.html. 
So far i have this:

base.html:

```
<li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Events
       <b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               {% if categories %}
                   {% for cat in category %}
                       <li><a href="{% url 'categories' pk=cat.pk %}">
                       {{ cat.name }}</a></li>
                   {% endfor %}
               {% else %}
                       There are no categories present.
               {% endif %}
           </ul>
</li>
```

views.py:

```
def categories(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'category': category})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^categories/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.categories, name='categories'),
```

So i want the drop down to display the available categories from the database and then when i click on one it will obviously load up the categories.html displaying the relevant category.

any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: sorry i forgot to say the problem i am having. 
Im not getting the drop down populated, and is only giving me the "there is no categories present"

Comment: So what's your question? What specific issues are you having?

Comment: sorry, its not populating, its just giving me the "there are no categories present"

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here:

Firstly, you don't have any context in your view called `categories`, yet you're checking for them in your template. Your view function is called 'categories', which might be creating some confusion for you. However, this is not context that is accessible to your view. It's just a function.

Secondly, you're not getting a list of categories (which you could iterate as you are in your template) in your view, you're getting a single category with:

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
# using the get() method means you're requesting a single object
```

So you need to do something more like:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
# here, we're getting a QuerySet (list of objects), rather a single object
```

Then add the `categories` to your context. So your view would end up looking like this:

```
def categories(request, pk):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'categories': categories})
```

Also, you'll need to change your iterator to iterate over `categories`, not `category`:

```
{% for cat in categories %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'categories' pk=cat.pk %}">
    {{ cat.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, i fully understand that now but unfortunately it is still not working, i am still receiving the "no categories are present".

Comment: Did you update your context dict in your render statement? Also do categories exist? `{% if categories %}` will return false if either a) The `categories` context doesn't exist OR b) the `categories` QuerySet is empty (no categories exist). I also updated my answer to reflect the new context (iterating over categories instead of category).

Comment: yes i updated the views.py as you have shown, (and the for loop in base.html) and i have a table in postgres named Category that i have put 4 test categories in but is still not showing in the drop down. Sorry to be a complete pain.

Comment: Print `categories` in your view and see if the queryset exists. This'll tell us if the problem lies in the view or the template

Comment: hi, sorry for the very late response. i have put print(categories) in the view.py and getting <function categories at 0x1047272f0> in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

So, "categories" variable will never give you "true", while you do not define it, and add it to template context.

Do this in your python code

```
def categories(request, pk):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'categories': categories})
```